# Membership.ValidateUser chatty with database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Not sure if I could be doing something wrong, or if I should just ditch the ASP.NET SQL Membership provider, and maybe roll our own.  I'm working hard to optimize our web app/service performance by reducing the number of database calls.  To that end, I've hooked up Entity Framework Profiler (EFProf), which is awesome.

It looks like from a single call to Membership.ValidateUser(username, password), I get 8 calls to the database.  4 selects, and 4 updates.  It seems the exact same sequence of selects and updates is repeated twice in a row.  It selects user data based on username, selects again based on userId, then updates the last login and last activity dates (the last two being sent as two separate update statements).

This becomes a somewhat bigger deal when we add in the fact that we're running on Azure, and thus the database is not housed on the same machine or right next to the web server, so each db call takes 3-10 ms on average.

Any thoughts on this?  Anyone noticed this behavior before?  Seems like this might just be something MSFT needs to optimize, but thought I'd ask anyhow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider are not supported on Azure and it is recommended to migrate to the [universal providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/16/migration-for-user-accounts-from-the-sqlmembershipprovider-to-the-universal-providers.aspx).  I'm not sure if that is the reason why it is so chatty, but the new providers have Azure support built-in.